# How to achieve Tensorflow Python model() (__call__) performance in C(++) API for small inputs?

Tags: python, c++, performance, tensorflow

**The problem**

I have a (very) small and fast model saved in the SavedModel format which I can load and run with the following code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./<SavedModelDir>")
outputs = model(inputs, training=False)
```

The predict function runs in 0.05 seconds with a batch of 5 inputs (on a Nvidia GPU).
If however I use `model.predict_on_batch(inputs)` or `model.predict(inputs)` the performance drops significantly to 0.65 - 0.80 seconds for a batch of 5. This is consistent with the documentation that states that using `model() (__call__)` is usually faster for smaller inputs.

The problem I am having is the fact that I am trying to port my model to a C(++) program. And using `TF_SessionRun()` for the C api and `model_bundle.GetSession()->Run()` I am getting performance similar to "slow" Python inference methods.

**What I have tried**

Another (very) small model with small batch, same result.

I tried disabling optimizations with `tf.config.optimizer.set_experimental_options({'disable_meta_optimizer': False})` to make sure this does not negatively impact performance but this made things even slower.

I also tried converting the SavedModel to a TensorRT SavedModel. This increases the performance of the `model() (__call__)` method even further but all the other methods stop working in Python and in the downloaded precompiled Tensorflow C GPU api (2.5.0) and the C++ API compiled with Tensorflow_CC I get an error about the operation not being found (TensorRT does not seem to work).

All the performance numbers given were run after a few warmup runs.
Performance measured both with Tensorflow profiler and Python's time.time

I checked if `model() (__call__)` is working correctly by checking the output and it is.

**My question(s)**

Is there a way to get `model() (__call__)` performance with the Tensorflow C(++) API?

The problem seems to be somewhere in Tensorflows optimization for larger batch sizes which decreases the performance of smaller batch sizes. Is there another API that allows faster inference on small batches out of the box (TensorRT C++ API?)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out by accident by doing the following for something else I was trying:

`tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()` at the top of the script. And then `print(len(outputs))` right after getting the outputs. This gives the following error: `TypeError: len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors.`.

By Googling I found out that symbolic tensors are tensors that do not directly hold values so the values are probably filled in later.

This means that `Model() (__call__)` does its computation asynchronous, timing the function gives us a false value. This can be "fixed" by stopping the time after printing/using every output or just using the `predict()` method to avoid this completely.